# Prove that $\sigma\{X_i:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}=\sigma\{\prod_{k=1}^iX_k:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, measurable-functions

Let $\{X_i:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$ be a set of random variables.

I want to show that $\sigma\{X_i:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}=\sigma\{\prod_{k=1}^iX_k:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$.

It is easy to see that $\sigma\{X_i:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}\supseteq\sigma\{\prod_{k=1}^iX_k:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$ since $\prod_{k=1}^iX_k$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma\{X_i:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$.

The other inclusion causes me problems:

$X_i=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^iX_k}{\prod_{k=1}^{i-1}X_k}$

I would like to say that both the numerator and the denominator are measurable with respect to $\sigma\{\prod_{k=1}^iX_k:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$ and therefore the entire fraction is measurable with respect to $\sigma\{\prod_{k=1}^iX_k:i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\}$.

Is this reasoning correct? Mainly I have doubts about divide-by-zero errors.

Comment: Are they assumed to be non-zero?

Comment: Clear false if $X_1=0$ and other $X_i$'s are non-trivial.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to know, the minimum conditions necessary for the proposition to be true. @SangchulLee

Comment: Is it enough to say that $X_i\neq0$ or should I say that $X_i(\omega)\neq0$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: You need $X_i(\omega) \neq 0$ for all $\omega$. It is not hard to find counter-examples without this condition.